# How to calculate the risk of conflicts of a 64 bit hash?

Tags: hash, types, conflict, uuid, bit

I need global unique ids for my application. I know there is an UUID standard for this, but I wonder if I really need 128 bits.

So I think about writing my own generator that uses system time, a random number, and the machines network address to generate an id that fits into 64 bit and therefore, can be stored in the `unsigned long long int` datatype in C++.

How can I determine if 64 bits is enough for me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

64 bit runs to about 18,446,744,073,709,551,616 combinations
which is around 18 and a half quintillion.

so if your'e generating 1.92 million hashes, the odds of a collision will be 1 in 10 million

[image: probability cheat sheet]

Source: http://preshing.com/20110504/hash-collision-probabilities

Comment: My idea was to generate the id by using something like a hash function. Directly using the properties wouldn't fit into the 64 bits I guess.

Comment: Exactly! - i've seen many people getting this wrong, so I was really just checking.

Comment: Good. So do you know how I can calculate the risk of a conflict for a given number of generated ids?

Comment: if you generate 607401 values the probability will be 1 in 100 million